# Migrate a perl module

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

Suppose that I have a perl module Foo::Bar, initiated with module-starter and already have several packages under the namespace Foo::Bar and now I came to the conclusion it was a bad choice for name and want to call it MyBetterName::Bar.

Are there any tool to help in automation this process, without the need to replace all modules, pods, tests and examples. I know, I can write a perl script to do that, but supose again it is the first time I wrote a perl module and don't know very well what files should be envolved.

I tried google but found nothing that seemed to me helpful

Comment: It hasn't been updated for a long time but maybe something like this: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Rename/lib/Module/Rename.pm

Comment: [»Frankly, this is the kind of thing you solve in five minutes with a macro in Emacs«](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: @daxim, supposing we know what files should be updated. It can even been done in vi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be enough to globally replace Foo::Bar and Foo/Bar

```
find -type f -exec perl -i -pe's{Foo(::|-|/)Bar}{MyBetterName${1}Bar}g;' {} +
```

Then rename the files themselves

```
find -depth -execdir rename 's/Foo/MyBetterName/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Yes It works with a minor change (including the hiffen)
find -type f -exec perl -i -pe's{Foo(::|/|-)Bar}{MyBetterName${1}Bar}g;' {} +

And adding this 
find . -depth -name "*" -execdir rename 's/Foo/MyBetterName/g' "{}" \; 
Thank you @ikegami for pointing me this single solution

Comment: Ah yes, I was actually thinking of the "-" when I said "/", though "/" good to include too